# Como dar quebra de linha em um Feed XML de acordo com a largura da página?

Tags: php, jquery, xml

Tenho uma tabela com 15 itens e preciso que seja feita a quebra das colunas quando o tamanho total dos itens atingir a largura total da tabela.

Ex.:

O que está acontecendo:

```
|--- WIDTH 300px ---|

01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

O que preciso que seja feito:

```
|--- WIDTH 300px ---|

01 02 03 04 05 06

07 08 09 10 11 12

13 14 15
```

---

Tenho este [feed](http://v2.afilio.com.br/aff/aff_boutique_show_ads.php?boutiqueid=37930-895835&currencypos=0&display_img=1&diplay_name=1&diplay_price=1&thumbsize=80%25&truncate_desc=15&numrows=1&numcols=20&colorname=000000&colorprice=E30000&bkcolor=FFFFFF&bordercolor=FFFFFF&self_target=0&) como exemplo e meu código atual é esse:

```
<div style="width:300px; max-width:300px">
    <?php
       $a = file_get_contents("http://v2.afilio.com.br/aff/aff_boutique_show_ads.php?boutiqueid=37930-895843&currencypos=0&display_img=1&diplay_name=1&diplay_price=1&thumbsize=80%&truncate_desc=15&numrows=1&numcols=20&colorname=000000&colorprice=E30000&bkcolor=FFFFFF&bordercolor=FFFFFF&self_target=0&");
       echo ($a);
    ?>    
</div>
```

Também gostaria de saber, é possível utilizar JavaScript ao invés de PHP?

Comment: Mathew, em que sentido você gostaria de usar Javascript no lugar de PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Mathew,

Na verdade você pode resolver simplesmente adicionando o style `word-wrap: break-word;` na sua div.

Exemplo, coloquei `120px` para dar o resultado do seu exemplo:

```html
<div style="width:120px;word-wrap: break-word; max-width:120px">
    <p>
    01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15
    </p>
</div>
```